# Pushing an element to every fourth place of a Float32Array efficiently in JS/TS

Tags: node.js, typescript, performance

I want to push a `1` to every fourth element of a Float32Array. My current solution is to convert said Float32Array into an array, iterating through it and applying `.splice` on every fourth element like so (I also convert the array to a buffer afterward but that is not relevant for this question):

```
function pushToEveryFourthAndConvertToBuffer(floatArray: Float32Array): Buffer {
  const array: number[] = [...floatArray];
  for (let i: number = 3; i <= array.length; i += 4) array.splice(i, 0, 1);
  return Buffer.from(array);
}
```

while this works, it is not performant at all. My Float32Array has 660000 entries (thus, the returned buffer has 880000) and this function gets called with about 100 different Float32Arrays. If I remove the for-loop from the function, it runs much faster so I can be very sure my method of applying the elements is causing the bottle neck.

Is there a more efficient way or does my CPU just have to suffer and do I have to wait really long since I don't want to implement a multi-threaded solution?

Edit:
I'll provide some input and expected output here to clarify my question:

```
new Float32Array([0, 0, 0,    0, 0, 0,    0, 0, 0]); // ← input
new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]); // ← output

new Float32Array([1, 2, 3,    4, 5, 6,    7, 8, 9]) // ← input
new Float32Array([1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 9]) // ← output

new Float32Array([0.2321, 0.294, 0.1246,    0.9352, 0.87423, 0.11]); // ← input
new Float32Array([0.2321, 0.294, 0.1246, 1, 0.9352, 0.87423, 0.11, 1]); // ← output
```

Comment: May I ask the reason, why you use Floar32? I'm asking, because I have never used this data structure. Thank you

Comment: @captain-yossarian I am using [brain.js](https://brain.js.org/) to create a neural network that analyzes changes being done to images and tries to apply the same changes on similar images. The return value of the run function is a Float32Array so I am working with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non concurrent way to do this might be something like this

```js
const initial_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

//  from now on we only work with Float32Array. No conversion until the end
const old_floats = new Float32Array(initial_array);

//  pre-allocate your new Float32Array because you know how big it needs to be
const new_floats = new Float32Array( Math.ceil(initial_array.length * 4 / 3) );

//  fill it with ones
new_floats.fill(1, 0);

//  for performance, simple loops are better than array methods
for (let i=0; i<old_floats.length/3; i++) {
  let read_start = i*3;
  let read_end = read_start+3;
  let write_start = i*4;
  let four_elements = old_floats.slice(read_start, read_end);
  new_floats.set(four_elements, write_start);
}

//  now let's convert back to numbers
console.log(new_floats);
```

For a concurrent way I would create 4 asynchronous functions. Function one would take every 3rd value, function two every 3rd+1, function three every 3rd+2, function 4 would simply inject "1" in every 4th value of the new array.

At the end, you would bring them together with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Your solution works like a charm! I had to edit one thing though: I guess you've misread my question and now I've provided some examples to further explain my problem. I want to insert a 1 *on* every fourth place, not *after*. Thus, I had to tweak the values; instead of `initial_array.length * 5 / 4` I use `initial_array.length * 4 / 3`, instead of `old_floats.length / 4` I use `old_floats.length / 3`, instead of `i*4` I use `i*3` and so forth (I somehow can't suggest an edit to your reply, I am not experienced in asking questions on SO)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have updated the answer accordingly. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to use `array.splice`? Compared to other array operations `splice` is **very slow**.

You can perform this same process by creating a new array with the expected size of your current one, and then assigning the values from the old array.

```js
function fillArray(floatArray) {
  const array = [];
  array.length = Math.floor(floatArray.length * 4/3 );

  for (let index = 0, negativeIndex = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if ((index + 1) % 4 === 0) {
      array[index] = 1;
      index++;
      negativeIndex--;
    }
    array[index] = floatArray[index + negativeIndex];
  }
  return Buffer.from(array);
}
```

Running this via jsbench in my browser shows that your splice version is 3 to 8 ops/sec, while my version is 1,500 to 1,600 ops/sec. (jsbench doesn't support buffers so you have to skip that last step)

If you want simpler code you could use array.push instead of defining the array length and keeping track of the negativeIndex, but that only performs 500 to 600 ops/sec and you were specifically looking for efficiency.